# How to clean Gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have a project in Android Studio that I need to share. So, I want to clean some local gradle files to reduce the size of the folder (eg: from 880Mb to 32Mb). 
Can anyone tell me how can I do to make it happen ?

Comment: Have you tried running `./gradlew clean`?

Comment: what do you want to clear? gradle cashes? then you can only delete cached files under ~/.gradle/caches In this case i also i don't understand why you should share this gradle files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it by doing this:

1. Enter the Terminal option
2. Type the command `gradlew clean`
3. And the trick was played.

[image]

Thank you for your contribution.